# How to speed up the apply function for lognormal distribution of Python code in Spyder

Tags: python, spyder

I'm trying to apply the lognormal distribution in the dataframe but have low memory issue if the simulation is set to 5,000,000 (as the codes shown below)

```
k['numlosses'] = np.random.poisson(9,5000000)

k['losses'] = k['numlosses']

k['losses'] = k['losses'].apply(lambda x: sum(np.random.lognormal(mu,sigma,(x,1))))
```

dataframe k is shown as below (this is just 50,000 simulations):

[image]

Based on this, I was just wondering is there any way to speed up this function

```
k['losses'] = k['losses'].apply(lambda x: sum(np.random.lognormal(mu,sigma,(x,1))))
```

for 5,000,000 simulations?

Comment: use numpy sum rather than native python sum?

Comment: thanks. but still got MemoryError using numpy sum

Comment: Speed and memory are 2 different problems. Please clarify your question.

Comment: It's a speed issue, just wondering is there any way to improve the speed for this large calculation, for example, 500 million simulations. Besides, I tried to use numpy sum instead and it indeed improved the speed. thanks a lot